# Can't read or write on database using php

Tags: php, mysql, database, web-applications, web

i'm developing a website so i store my data in db4free.net -free online database-, but i can't read or write or eveen select the database (error: Error in query: . SELECT command denied to user ''@'localhost' for table 'first') but i tryed heidiSQL -desktop application to manage DBs over networks- it worked correctly and i can select,insert and delete.
this is my php code:

```
$conn=mysqli_connect("db4free.net:3306","usr","pass");
$sql = "select * from test1.first";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error in query: $query. ".mysql_error());
```

any help please ?

Comment: You are using `mysql_query` but `mysqli_connect()` (notice the i)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
$conn=mysql_connect("db4free.net","usr","pass",3306);
```

Comment: Great, however you should be using `MySQLi_` and not `MySQL_` --- better yet, PDO.

Comment: @Fred-ii-please can you tell me why?

Comment: `MySQL_` is deprecated, meaning it will be deleted in upcoming PHP releases. Also using `MySQLi_` is safer, however PDO is even better/safer.

Comment: Have a look for yourself, see the link http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php and read the Warning.